# How do I check where the php parameter come from?I

Tags: php, parameters, request

I'm code reviewing php code and checked the parameters given with

```php
$params = $_GET;
var_dump($params);

//result
array(5) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "2020-02-03"
  ["flag"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["target"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["anorher_flag"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["url"]=>
  string(20) "foo/bar/sth/"
}
```

I want to check where that 'url' parameter is come from. Where was it passed from. But the code/structure is too long and confusing to find where the 'url' is.. (and since url is very common name, over 300result search with 'url'..)

Is there any useful command or function to check where specific parameter passed from?

Comment: `$_GET` is the URL query parameters. So unless you have code that's assigning to `$_GET`, it came from the client.

Comment: To illustrate what Barmar said, the script was likely accessed by http://fake.net?date=2020-02-03&flag=0&target=0&anorher_flag=1&url=foo/bar/sth/.

Comment: It strongly assumed there's code that asign those parameters. I want to know if there anything like (pseudo: $_PASS['url'] = foo/bar/sth). then I can search with '$_PASS' and get to know where 'url' passed from.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from **$_SERVER** variable.

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']
```

You will get the complete URL from where Data is Posted